# Automatic vacuum fails with `ERROR: XX000: cache lookup failed for type 0`

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I've been noticing something like this popping up every 15 seconds in my server logs:

```
2020-01-30 21:10:30 UTC::@:[24969]:ERROR: XX000: cache lookup failed for type 0
2020-01-30 21:10:30 UTC::@:[24969]:CONTEXT: automatic vacuum of table "myschema.mytable"
2020-01-30 21:10:30 UTC::@:[24969]:LOCATION: get_typlenbyval, lsyscache.c:2036
```

When I manually run a `VACUUM ANALYZE myschema.mytable;` it runs without any error, and the error in my logs goes away. However, inevitably, it returns again at some point.

The table in question is defined as follows:

```
tfs_dev=> \d myschema.mytable;
                                                   Table "myschema.mytable"
   Column    |   Type    | Collation | Nullable |                                  Default
-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 level       | text      |           | not null |
 id          | integer   |           | not null | nextval('myschema.mytable_id_seq'::regclass)
 text_id     | text      |           |          |
 name        | text      |           |          |
 geom        | geometry  |           |          |
 valid_dates | tstzrange |           |          | tstzrange(NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::timestamp with time zone)
 adjacent    | integer[] |           |          |
 valence     | integer   |           |          |
 color       | smallint  |           |          | 0
Indexes:
    "mytable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (level, id)
    "mytable_text_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (text_id)
    "mytable_gix" gist (level, geom, id, text_id, name)
    "mytable_spgix" spgist (geom)
    "mytable_text_id_ix" btree (text_id, level, id, name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "otherschema.othertable" CONSTRAINT "othertable_mytable_fk" FOREIGN KEY (level, level_id) REFERENCES myschema.mytable(level, id)
    TABLE "otherschema.othertable2" CONSTRAINT "othertable2_mytable_fk" FOREIGN KEY (level, level_id) REFERENCES myschema.mytable(level, id)
```

Many other posts with a similar error seem to be about a foreign data wrapper, which is present in this database, but not with this table/schema.

Comment: Strange. Do you have a problem with `SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable;`?

Comment: Nope. Selects all records just fine, and no errors show up in the log as a result. Also worth noting, I can easily get it to start erroring again by doing `update mytable set id=id;`, and stop it by vacuuming manually.

Comment: Must be some weird kind of data corruption. Dump and restore the whole cluster to a new instance to get rid of it.

Comment: Interesting. I dumped and restored on a new instance, and saw a few of these pop up during index creation as I was restoring. Specifically, it occurred on all 3 `spgist` indexes I have in the database. 

`2020-02-05 08:42:58 UTC:1.2.3.4(36002):myuser@mydb:[30299]:ERROR: XX000: cache lookup failed for type 0
2020-02-05 08:42:58 UTC:1.2.3.4(36002):myuser@mydb:[30299]:LOCATION: get_typlenbyval, lsyscache.c:2036
2020-02-05 08:42:58 UTC:1.2.3.4(36002):myuser@mydb:[30299]:STATEMENT: CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable USING spgist (geom) WHERE (column1 IS NULL);`

Comment: Seems very much like https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Querying-foreign-table-with-SP-GiST-index-results-in-ERROR-cache-lookup-failed-for-type-0-td6090679.html, except that I am not accessing these tables over FDW. I should be able to rewrite these as GIST indexes for my purposes, though the cause is still mysterious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your investigation uncovered, you are suffering from [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1407840601.3022762.1560857315693%40mail.yahoo.com) PostGIS bug ([bug number #4440](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4440)).

Your options:

- Update PostGIS to the latest minor release. The bug has been fixed in June 2019.
- Workaround: Use GiST rather than SP-GiST indexes.

Comment: I have PostGIS installed in `public`, which _should_ already always be on my search_path, so I'm not sure about Workaround 1. But Workaround 2 should be sufficient for the moment. Thanks!

Comment: Hm; I'd say upgrading is the simplest option... Perhaps something that uses PostGIS (other user, security definer function) has a different `search_path` set.

Comment: Hmm.. well, the two ways I'm seeing this happen is during autovacuum, and during pg_restore index creation. The pg_restore makes sense, because for whatever reason the dump has `SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false)` at the top. But what would autovacuum be using as a search_path? 

Upgrading would have been my first choice too, but we're running on AWS RDS so the PostGIS version is out of my control. The latest supported PG there (11.6) is still running PostGIS 2.5.2.

Comment: Ah, that makes everything clear. It has nothing to do with a user-set `search_path`: both autovacuum and `pg_dump` must not pick up objects from a random `search_path` like `public`, so they fix it to `pg_catalog`. That triggers the error.

Comment: But when I run `SELECT pg_catalog.current_setting('search_path');` on the database it returns `"$user", public` .. shouldn't autovacuum/pg_dump pick that up?

Comment: For security reasons, autovacuum sets the `search_path` explicitly to `pg_catalog`. Think of what happens in this case: autovacuum processes the index, the C code behind the index functions is built in a buggy fashion so that it is sensitive to `search_path`, it tries to access a database object by name. If I as an attacker know that, I could make the code access my malicious object instead, and could cause all kind of trouble.